# Use build.gradle for deployment

Tags: java, gradle, deployment, build.gradle, buildship

I'm learning how to use gradle to build my java applications. Currently I'm using eclipse with buildship plugin. I have it building my JARs and WARs, and also have gradle running my JUnit and Selenium tests. I like that it pulls in the dependencies I need as I need them during development.

It seems like it would make sense if my build.gradle files define my dependencies to build and run my application in dev then I should be able to use them for deployment. Otherwise I have to retrieve all my dependencies by some other means and deploy to my production environment, and managing 2 different methods of retrieving and deploying dependencies seems to be a risk for problems.

Can I use gradle or at least my build.gradle files in some way for my deployment?

Comment: Your JAR or WAR should contain all necessary dependencies in order to deploy your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [gradle distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html). This plugin adds tasks to create an "install folder" or an archive file (zip or tar) containing all the dependencies you'll need to execute/deploy your application.

[Gradle application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) also generates shell/bat scripts to invoke your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Between Adam's comment and this Answer I think I was able to get my app packaged. Thank you!